# ArcMap cloud removal process

Tags: arcmap, classification, reclassify, cloud-cover

I am working with Landsat 8 data.  I have performed the necessary pre-processes that I want (atmospheric and topographic correction and pan-sharpening, using QGIS and ERDAS).  I am now working on removing clouds and cloud shadow.  I used the "Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification" tool first.  I then manually color coated vegetation vs. cloud/shadow coverage (red and green).  I used the "reclassfy" tool to combine the two classes.

I am stuck with:
Now I want to make the cloud/shadow coverage value 0 and the vegetation value 1.  Then multiple that by my original pre-processed Landsat 8 image.  This way all the pixels with the cloud/shadow coverage will disappear, but make sure I keep the RGB bands from the original.  Any suggestions?

I have tried multiplying the cloud/shadow and vegetation data by the original in the raster calculator and I get an output with no clouds, but the RGB bands are no longer there.

Comment: Have you tried something like this in the raster calculator (not tested) `Con(binary == 0, 0, original_raster)`, where `binary` is your 0-1 cloud/shadow - vegetation raster?

Comment: I have not tried that.  I will try it soon.  I just got it to work in ERDAS by assigning the cloud/shadow vegetation raster as a float single.

Comment: If using the ArcGIS raster calculator, you need to multiply each band separately and then recombine them.

Comment: @user2856 Thank you that works, but its a bit time consuming since I have to take each band apart, multiply them individually and then recombine them.  I found an alternate solution with ERDAS that uses the Model Maker.  Much faster.